# Background image won't fit around video

Tags: html, css

I can't for the life of me get my video to fit in the background image. I am not sure if I should just add the background in html. I think I just have to change background-position and size and I have tried but I still can't get it to fit. Any help would be appreciated!

```
                <div id="video1">
        <iframe width="450" height="315"src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vr0dXfQQfNU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    <div id="video2">
  <iframe width="450" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fevkx229XBs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
</div>



            div#video1 {
float: right;
background-image: url(images/vidborder.png);
background-size: 110%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: -50px center;
width: 500px;
height: 450px;
   }

              div#video2 {
background-image: url(images/vidborder2.png);
background-size: 10%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 500px;
height: 450px;

          }

          .videos {
margin-top: 40px;
          }

         iframe {margin-top: 35px;}
```